# CSS dropdown menu jumping

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm stuck with a drop down menu. The problem is that the "parent" link is jumping.

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><span>Page 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Extralong Page 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a>Page 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a>Page 1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><span>Page 3</span>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Page 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a>Long description for page 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a>Page 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a>Page 3.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav {
        float: right;
    }

        #nav ul {
            float: left;
        }

        #nav li {
            float: left;
            padding-top: 2px;
            list-style: none;
            background: #3451ff;
        }

            #nav li a,
            #nav li span {
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 12pt;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 13px 10px 9px 10px;
            }

                #nav li a:link, #nav li a:active, #nav li a:visited,
                #nav li span {
                    color: #FFF;
                }

                #nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active,
                #nav li span:hover {
                    color: #000;
                }

            #nav li li {
                display: none;
            }

            #nav li:hover li {
                display: block;
                float: none;
                background: #555;
            }

        #nav li li a {
            font-size: 10pt;
            margin: 1px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #3c6f3a;
            padding: 5px 0;
        }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gmU55/)

How can I make this parent static such that it's width isn't changed on hover? I don't want to use js.

Comment: Did you check the offending elements (and the surrounding ones) with dev tools? A great one is Chrome > Elements > Computed. Select elements you want to check in Elements. Then look at Computed when you perform changes, to see if there is – ahem – any changes. Makes it easier to pinpoint the actual culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a width for the parent:

```
#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100px; /* Add this bad boy */
    background: #3451ff;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/gmU55/1/)

Comment: Thanks! Is there still a way without setting a fixed width?

Comment: @Explicat Well without a set width the `<li>` will be as long as your text it contains [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/gmU55/4/). Scroll over page1 and you will see its super long now. Need a width to control that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:absolute` and make its parent li `position:relative` [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gmU55/2/)

```
#nav ul {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
 }
```

Comment: Look at the menu, it looks pretty bad with the first drop down "bugging out" to the left.

Comment: @Ruddy : but its better than jumping :D :D

Comment: Is it tho? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/gmU55/6/). Its now off the screen. Its not a good way to do it, if its the same `width` as the parent it cant go "missing". Good idea tho.

Answer (score 0):

Use position:relative for ul parent and give position:absolute for parent child..it will be working fine.

Here is the updated fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/gmU55/5/

```
#nav li li {
                display: none;
                 position:relative;
            }

            #nav li:hover li {
                display: block;
                float: none;
                position:absolute;
                background: #555;
            }
```

Comment: You should take another look at what you have done. All the links are merged into one under the parent.